# VSCode extension for enforcing the "Google HTML/CSS Style Guide"

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I edit a lot of CSS files and SCSS files in VS Code.

Is there an Extension for Visual Studio Code that enforces complicance to the [Google HTML/CSS Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html)?

It does *not* have to be a special-purpose, single-purpose Extension.
I would also be willing to

- to use a general-purpose CSS linter extension,  or
- to spend some time on tweaking VSCode's built-in rules for CSS linting.

In other words, if someone has developed a config file with all those rules, (similar to an `.eslintrc.json` config file for enforcing JavaScript linting), I would use that.